# Secure Way of storing Passwords to APIs without OpenID?

Tags: security, passwords, eventbrite, confidentiality

I asked a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897777/storing-passwords-for-external-apis-best-practice) a while back but all the answers were offering OpenID which is nice but it doesn't work with services that require authentication that don't use it (such as EventBrite).

Say I want to create an app that lists your events from event brite, and their analytics (which eventbrite includes).  Any person can sign up for this service to list their events.  But since EventBrite doesn't have OpenID to authenticate, I need to somehow get the user login and password to EventBrite.

Some possible solutions are:

1. Store credentials in YAML [like this](http://github.com/openrain/action_mailer_tls/blob/master/generators/templates/config/smtp_gmail.yml.sample).  Easily hackable.
2. Have user enter in credentials into a form on my site, I save the credentials to my database, and use them to login to EventBrite.  Easily hackable.
3. Have user enter in credentials and I pass them directly to EventBrite without saving, and I save the response header Cookies to the database, and when they expire, have them login again.  Is this easily hackable?

This hypothetical service also wants to automatically check events (say via cron), so it doesn't depend on the user going to my site via the browser.  So cookies or credientials need to be stored somewhere.

The thing is, [after asking this similar question about confidentiality and security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674384/why-shouldnt-i-programmatically-submit-username-password-to-facebook-twitter-ama) it sounds like you should *never* build an application that does what I'm describing.  There's got to be some way building something like this is okay.

What is that way?  What am I missing?  Is it okay to go with #3 and save the cookies (but still needing the user to submit their email/password via a form which I send to Eventbrite)?  What is an acceptable solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a secure way to do this. You can employ workarounds, but that's about it.

1. Storing passwords in YAML or XML in cleartext is definitely out
2. In fact, even encrypting and storing passwords is wrong. Your application would need a way to decrypt the passwords, so the attacker can also decrypt the passwords.
3. The recommended way to store passwords is Salt + Hash, but because it becomes unrecoverable, it is useless in your case.
4. Because of 2 & 3, no matter where you store the users credentials, you are vulnerable.
5. Storing the cookies instead of the passwords is a better idea. But again, this involves the password going through your website, which isn't good.

Given your situation, storing the cookie is a better approach. Use HTTPS throughout, even on your website. Its less than ideal though, and you and your users should be aware of it.

Comment: I doubt you can get and store a cookie not belonging to your domain. If you could do that, everyone could hijack it.

Comment: He's making a server-to-server call to the remote website, so he can get the cookie. The restriction you mention only applies to browsers to prevent one website from reading the data/cookies of another website.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly the use case I was trying to describe :).  As long as consumers are aware that we're doing this, and we have principles and ethics, it should be fine.  If someone got ahold of the cookies from the database, could they do anything with that?

Comment: If they get hold of the cookies, they can do whatever you are doing. It has its own risks, but it is better than storing passwords in the db. Cookies atleast expire.

Answer (score 1):

Eventbrite has recently release new documentation describing [how to implement OAuth2.0 for cross-site user authentication](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/oauth2/).
I would recommend using our [javascipt-based OAuth2.0 widget](http://eventbrite.github.com/oauth2-example.html), which stores the user's authentication tokens in their browser's localStorage by default.
Since the auth tokens are stored in the user's browser, and are prevented from being accessed by other domains, it's not likely that there would be any security leaks.

The need for email and password combos are completely avoided in this authentication scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Most sites only support direct login with the original cleartext password, so you have to get, store and provide that too. And I would never ever trust you with that.
The problem with your concept is that you require the password to be given to a third party. The solution is not to involve a third party, for example my browser is pretty good at storing and filling in passwords for me automatically (my hard-drive is password protected too). And they are dozens of other password wallet apps too. I wouldn't gain anything by subscribing, using your service.

Before going into such a business, consider you are going to be the #1 target. Facebook, Google are incredibly paranoid about security, spending a lot of time, money and effort to keep the logins safe. Do you have the same resources? Then you are a better target. Also by hacking your service, they immediately get multiple accounts, passwords of your users, also seeing who is always reusing its password.

Answer (score 0):

For working with the Eventbrite API, I'd recommend ensuring that all connections are over SSL, and that you authenticate using a user_key rather than a username and password.

More information about authentication for the Eventbrite API is here: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/auth/

After logging in, users can find their user_key here: http://www.eventbrite.com/userkeyapi

This should prevent username and password information from being intercepted over the wire, or read from a local data store.