# Get list of users events from evenbrite using the api

Tags: eventbrite

I'm trying to build an application that will list events that a user has created on eventbrite using. So the application will have multiple users and for each user, i want to be able to get their event list from eventbrite.

Do i need each user's username and password to do that. What parameters do i need and does the eventbrite api support this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on whether these users have public or private event data.

For public events that have an associated "organizer profile" page, you can use the [organizer_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/organizer_list_events/) API call without providing any additional authentication credentials.
The event_search method may also work well for finding upcoming public events by organizer.

If you want to access both public and private event data, or events that have ended, then you will need to supply some user authentication credentials.  The [user_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_events/) API call is probably your best choice in this case.

The most simple method of authenticating as an Eventbrite user involves providing a user_key  in your API request.  Each user should be able to find their user_key here: eventbrite.com/userkeyapi/

More info on user authentication is available on the Eventbrite developer site:
developer.eventbrite.com/doc/auth/#user_authentication

Comment: Thank you ryanj for your answer. I will provide both the option of username and password and user key to users. which ever they prefer. However i want to know if they support xml also.

Answer (score 0):

XML is definitely a supported API response output format.

We have recently launched [support for OAuth2.0](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/oauth2/).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674942/secure-way-of-storing-passwords-to-apis-without-openid/9137366#9137366) may contain some useful information on that subject:
[Secure Way of storing Passwords to APIs without OpenID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674942/secure-way-of-storing-passwords-to-apis-without-openid/9137366#9137366)